Have anyone know the base position of EFI_DISK_IO_PROTOCOL will change in process when using WriteDisk or ReadDisk?
I am using free pascal to format the virtual hard disk (my base hard disk have maximum 4GiB),but when I execute the uefi app and after that I discovered my hard disk is not formatted in GPT format and fdisk told me it is unknown.
These are my related code:
efi_lba=qword;
     mbr_partition_record=packed record
                          BootIndicator:byte;
                          StartHead:byte;
                          StartSector:byte;
                          StartTrack:byte;
                          OSIndicator:byte;
                          EndHead:byte;
                          EndSector:byte;
                          EndTrack:byte;
                          StartingLBA:dword;
                          SizeinLBA:dword;
                          end;
     master_boot_record=packed record
                        BootStrapCode:array[1..440] of byte;
                        UniqueMbrSignature:array[1..4] of byte;
                        Unknown:array[1..2] of byte;
                        Partition:array[1..4] of mbr_partition_record;
                        Signature:word;
                        end;
     efi_guid=record
              data1:dword;
              data2:word;
              data3:word;
              data4:array[1..8] of byte;
              end;
     efi_gpt_header=packed record
                    signature:qword;
                    Revision:dword;
                    HeaderSize:dword;
                    HeaderCRC32:dword;
                    Reserved:dword;
                    MyLBA:dword;
                    AlternateLBA:qword;
                    FirstUsableLBA:qword;
                    LastUsableLBA:qword;
                    DiskGuid:efi_guid;
                    PartitionEntryLBA:qword;
                    NumberOfPartitionEntries:dword;
                    SizeOfPartitionEntry:dword;
                    PartitionEntryArrayCRC32:dword;
                    end;
     efi_partition_entry=packed record
                         PartitionTypeGUID:efi_guid;
                         UniquePartitionGUID:efi_guid;
                         StartingLBA:efi_lba;
                         EndingLBA:efi_lba;
                         Attributes:qword;
                         PartitionName:array[1..36] of WideChar;
                         end;
efi_disk_interface_list=record
                       disk_interface:^Pefi_disk_io_protocol;
                       disk_count:qword;
                       end;
    efi_block_interface_list=record
                       block_interface:^Pefi_block_io_protocol;
                       block_count:qword;
                       end;
    efi_gpt_entry_array=record
                        entry_content:^efi_partition_entry;
                        entry_count:word;
                        end;
    efi_gpt_partition_array_content=record
                                    startlba,endlba:qword;
                                    end;
    efi_gpt_partition_array=record
                            array_content:^efi_gpt_partition_array_content;
                            array_count:qword;
                            end;
function efi_detect_disk(SystemTable:Pefi_system_table):efi_disk_interface_list;cdecl;[public,alias:'EFI_DETECT_DISK'];
var diskiopro:Pointer;
    i,totalnum:natuint;
    totalbuf:Pefi_handle;
    funclist:efi_disk_interface_list;
begin
 SystemTable^.BootServices^.LocateHandleBuffer(ByProtocol,@efi_disk_io_protocol_guid,nil,totalnum,totalbuf);
 funclist.disk_interface:=allocmem(sizeof(Pointer)*1024); funclist.disk_count:=totalnum;
 for i:=1 to totalnum do
  begin
   SystemTable^.BootServices^.HandleProtocol((totalbuf+i-1)^,@efi_disk_io_protocol_guid,diskiopro);
   (funclist.disk_interface+i-1)^:=Pefi_disk_io_protocol(diskiopro);
  end;
 efi_detect_disk:=funclist;
end;
function efi_detect_block(SystemTable:Pefi_system_table):efi_block_interface_list;cdecl;[public,alias:'EFI_DETECT_BLOCK'];
var blockiopro:Pointer;
    i,totalnum:natuint;
    totalbuf:Pefi_handle;
    funclist:efi_block_interface_list;
begin
 SystemTable^.BootServices^.LocateHandleBuffer(ByProtocol,@efi_block_io_protocol_guid,nil,totalnum,totalbuf);
 funclist.block_interface:=allocmem(sizeof(Pointer)*1024); funclist.block_count:=totalnum;
 for i:=1 to totalnum do
  begin
   SystemTable^.BootServices^.HandleProtocol((totalbuf+i-1)^,@efi_block_io_protocol_guid,blockiopro);
   (funclist.block_interface+i-1)^:=Pefi_block_io_protocol(blockiopro);
  end;
 efi_detect_block:=funclist;
end;
procedure efi_clear_disk(DiskList:efi_disk_interface_list;BlockList:efi_block_interface_list;number:natuint);cdecl;[public,alias:'EFI_CLEAR_LIST'];
var buf:PByte;
    i:qword;
begin
 buf:=allocmem(1048576);
 for i:=1 to efi_get_disk_size(Blocklist,number) div 1048576 do
  begin
((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^)^.WriteDisk((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^,((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.MediaId,(i-1)*1048576,1048576,Pointer(buf));
  end;
end;
procedure efi_main_zone_disk(DiskList:efi_disk_interface_list;BlockList:efi_block_interface_list;number:natuint;partarray:efi_gpt_partition_array);cdecl;[public,alias:'EFI_MAIN_ZONE_DISK'];
var i:natuint;
    blocksize:word;
    pos,pos2:qword;
    fmbr:master_boot_record;
    fgpt:efi_gpt_header;
    fepe:efi_partition_entry;
    partname:PWideChar;
begin
 //blocksize:=((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.Blocksize;
 blocksize:=128;
 for i:=1 to 440 do fmbr.BootStrapCode[i]:=0;
 for i:=1 to 4 do fmbr.UniqueMbrSignature[i]:=0;
 for i:=1 to 2 do fmbr.unknown[i]:=0;
 for i:=1 to 4 do
  begin
   if(i=1) then
    begin
     fmbr.partition[i].bootindicator:=1;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartHead:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartSector:=$02;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartTrack:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].OSindicator:=$EE;
     fmbr.partition[i].EndHead:=$FF;
     fmbr.partition[i].EndSector:=$FF;
     fmbr.partition[i].EndTrack:=$FF;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartingLBA:=$00000001;
     fmbr.partition[i].SizeInLBA:=$FFFFFFFF;
    end
   else if(i>1) then
    begin
     fmbr.partition[i].bootindicator:=0;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartHead:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartSector:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartTrack:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].OSindicator:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].EndHead:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].EndSector:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].EndTrack:=$00;
     fmbr.partition[i].StartingLBA:=$00000000;
     fmbr.partition[i].SizeInLBA:=$00000000;
    end;
  end;
  fmbr.Signature:=$AA55;
  ((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^)^.WriteDisk((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^,((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.MediaId,0,sizeof(master_boot_record),Pointer(@fmbr));
  fgpt.signature:=$5459445120494645;
  fgpt.revision:=$00010000;
  fgpt.headersize:=512;
  fgpt.headercrc32:=0;
  fgpt.reserved:=0;
  fgpt.myLBA:=1;
  fgpt.AlternateLBA:=((Blocklist.block_interface+number-1)^)^.Media^.LastBlock;
  if(partarray.array_count mod 4<>0) then
   begin
    fgpt.FirstUsableLBA:=2+partarray.array_count div 4+1;
    fgpt.LastUsableLBA:=((Blocklist.block_interface+number-1)^)^.Media^.LastBlock-(partarray.array_count div 4+2);
   end
  else
   begin
    fgpt.FirstUsableLBA:=2+partarray.array_count div 4;
    fgpt.LastUsableLBA:=((Blocklist.block_interface+number-1)^)^.Media^.LastBlock-(partarray.array_count div 4+1);
   end;
  fgpt.diskguid:=partition_system_guid;
  fgpt.PartitionEntryLBA:=partarray.array_count;
  fgpt.NumberOfPartitionEntries:=partarray.array_count;
  fgpt.sizeofPartitionEntry:=sizeof(efi_partition_entry);
  fgpt.PartitionEntryArrayCRC32:=0;
 ((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^)^.WriteDisk((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^,((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.MediaId,sizeof(master_boot_record),sizeof(efi_gpt_header),Pointer(@fgpt));
 ((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^)^.WriteDisk((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^,((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.MediaId,(efi_get_disk_size(BlockList,number)-sizeof(efi_gpt_header)) div blocksize*blocksize,sizeof(efi_gpt_header),Pointer(@fgpt));
 pos:=((sizeof(master_boot_record)+sizeof(efi_gpt_header)) div blocksize+1)*blocksize;
 pos2:=((efi_get_disk_size(BlockList,number)-sizeof(efi_gpt_header)) div blocksize-partarray.array_count)*blocksize;
 for i:=1 to partarray.array_count do
  begin
   if(i=1) then
    begin
     fepe.PartitionTypeGUID:=efi_system_partition_guid;
     fepe.UniquePartitionGUID:=partition_system_guid;
     fepe.StartingLBA:=fgpt.FirstUsableLBA+(partarray.array_content+i-1)^.startlba;
     fepe.EndingLBA:=fgpt.FirstUsableLBA+(partarray.array_content+i-1)^.endlba;
     fepe.Attributes:=0; 
    end
   else
    begin
     fepe.PartitionTypeGUID:=partition_system_guid;
     fepe.UniquePartitionGUID:=partition_system_guid;
     fepe.StartingLBA:=fgpt.FirstUsableLBA+(partarray.array_content+i-1)^.startlba;
     fepe.EndingLBA:=fgpt.FirstUsableLBA+(partarray.array_content+i-1)^.endlba;
     fepe.Attributes:=0; 
    end;
   fepe.PartitionName[1]:='Z';
   fepe.PartitionName[2]:='o';
   fepe.PartitionName[3]:='n';
   fepe.PartitionName[4]:='e';
   fepe.PartitionName[5]:=#0;
   ((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^)^.WriteDisk((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^,((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.MediaId,pos,sizeof(efi_partition_entry),Pointer(@fepe));
   pos:=pos+sizeof(efi_partition_entry);
   ((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^)^.WriteDisk((DiskList.disk_interface+number-1)^,((blocklist.block_interface+i-1)^)^.Media^.MediaId,pos2,sizeof(efi_partition_entry),Pointer(@fepe));
   pos2:=pos2+sizeof(efi_partition_entry);
  end;
end;

And these are related codes in efi_main function:
efi_clear_disk(efi_interface_list,efi_block_list,1);
efi_main_zone_disk(efi_interface_list,efi_block_list,1,gpe);

build.sh:
#fpc -XPx86_64-w64-mingw32- -Aas -n -O4 -Si -Sc -Sg -Xd -CX -XXs -Px86_64 -Rintel -Twin64 -Cg -Us system.pas
fpc -XPx86_64-w64-mingw32- -Aas -n -O4 -Si -Sc -Sg -Xd -CX -XXs -Px86_64 -Rintel -Twin64 -Cg uefimain.pas
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --gc-sections -shared -Bsymbolic -nostdlib --oformat pei-x86-64 uefimain.o uefi.o system.o -e efi_main -o main.dll
objcopy -I pei-x86-64 -O efi-app-x86_64 main.dll bootx64.efi
dd if=/dev/zero of=fat.img bs=512 count=131072
/usr/sbin/mkfs.vfat -F 32 fat.img
mmd -i fat.img ::/EFI
mmd -i fat.img ::/EFI/BOOT
#mmd -i fat.img ::/EFI/DRIVERS
mcopy -i fat.img bootx64.efi ::/EFI/BOOT
#mcopy -i fat.img Drivers/*.efi ::EFI/DRIVERS
mkdir iso
cp fat.img iso
xorriso -as mkisofs -R -f -e fat.img -no-emul-boot -o cdimage.iso iso
qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -m 2048 -hda test.vmdk -net none -cdrom cdimage.iso
rm -rf iso
rm -rf *.ppu
rm -rf fat.img
rm -rf *.o

img.sh:
qemu-img create -f vmdk test.vmdk 4G

This functions with efi_* is in the UEFI API,not in the code.
When the efi_main function ends,I discover the hard disk after using OpenSUSE's fdisk is not formatted as GPT format,WHY?
I want a correct edit advice to solve my problem in disk operating.
